# how to set width for messagebox in GXT/GWT?

Tags: gwt

how to set width for message box? or how can we format the message that we display in the message box into multiple lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`setMinWidth`](http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/MessageBox.html#setMinWidth%28int%29) and [`setMaxWidth`](http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/MessageBox.html#setMaxWidth%28int%29) functions to set the minimum/maximum width for the `MessageBox` in pixels.